# Create object using new $this

Tags: php, oop

Why `new $this` works? I understand `new self` or `new static` but cant find anything for `$this`:

```
class Foo {
    private $str;
    public function __construct($str) {
        $this->str = $str;
    }
    public function test($str) {
        return new $this($str);
    }
}
$bar = new Foo('bar');
var_dump($bar->test('TEST'));
```

Comment: *"but cant find anything for $this"* - Oh? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php *"The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object)."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning a new instance of itself, from within an instantiated class.

The `self` and `static` examples would be used for when being called statically, or from outside an instance of the class.

You see by comparing the `$bar` with `$bar->test('TEST')` that they have difference identifiers.

It's equivalent to this:

```
public function test($str) {
    $class = get_class($this);
    return new $class($str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying to accomplish is:

```
$foo = clone $this;
```

See this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php). Hope it helps